# Understanding byte array values

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
//this line makes sense...I always get 4 which is expected
int count = BitConverter.GetBytes(i).Length;

//This is the line that produces results I'm confused by
byte[] valArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
```

So here are some numbers I have set `i` to and the results I see in the byte array.

1. > X = 0
   >   0  0  0  0

---

2. > X = 37
   >   37  0  0  0

---

3. > X = 257
   >   1  1  0  0

---

4. > X = 256
   >   0  1  0  0

---

5. > X = 255
   >   255  0  0  0

Sample 3 and 4 are the ones that are really throwing me. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Are you sure #4 isn't 0 1 0 0 ?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException...you are correct. It is 0 1 0 0...updating OP.

Comment: What instead do you expect to get for #3 and #4?

Comment: @lc. Well...perhaps for 3:  255  2  0  0...

Comment: Have you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: And [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

due to the x86 endianness the value that the byte array represents is

```
b0 + (b1 * 256) + (b2 * 256 * 256) + (b3 * 256 * 256 * 256)
```

so #4 is

```
0 + (1 * 256) + 0 + 0 = 256
```

And #3 is left as an exercise for the reader

Comment: If I understand this correctly then 3 would be 1 + (1*256) +0 +0

Comment: X = 600 would be 88  2  0  0  and if I read wiki correctly this is little endian

Comment: Yes, on x86 the architecture is little endian.